# Using an "uncommon" delimiter for creating arrays in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I am building an app in Ruby on Rails in which I am pulling in content another file, and wonder if there's any simple way to create a unique delimiter for separating string content, or whether there's another approach I should take.

Let's say I have a paragraph of text, I'd like to pull in, and let's say I don't know what the text will contain.

What I would like to do is put some sort of delimiter at, let's say, 5 random points in the paragraph so that, later on, an array can be created in which content up to that delimiter can be separated out into an individual element.

For a bit of context, let's say I have a paragraph pulled in as a string:

```
Hello, this is a paragraph of text which will be delimited. Goodbye.
```

Now, let's say I add a delimiter at various points, as follows (I know how to do this in code):

```
Hello, this [DELIMITER] is a paragraph [DELIMITER] of text which [DELIMITER] will [DELIMITER] be delimitted. Goodbye.
```

Again, I know how to do this, but let's say I'm able to use the above to create an array as follows:

```
my_array = ["Hello, this", "is a paragraph", "of text which", "will", "be delimitted. Goodbye"
```

I'm confident of achieving all of the above. The challenge I'm having is: what should my delimiter be?

Normally, commas are used as delimiters but, if the text already includes a comma, this will result in delimitations where I do not wish them to occur. In the above example, for example, the comma between "Hello" and "this" would cause the "Hello, this" element to be split up into "Hello" and "this"—not what I want.

What I *have* thought of doing is using a random (hex) number generator to create a new delimiter each time the page is loaded, e.g. "Hello, this 023ABCDEF is a paragraph 023ABCDEF...", but I'm not sure this is the correct approach.

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Could you maybe store a list of length in characters (like 50, 70, 40 etc) that would tell you where to cut later, instead of inserting delimiters? Getting the array would be a bit harder than calling `split`, but not that hard using something like `slice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multipart mime messages take (more or less) the approach of a GUID separator; it's adequate.

I view this as a different type of problem, though, closer to a text editor marking sections of text **bold**, or *italic*, etc. That can be handled via string parsing (a la Markdown, SO's formatting) or data structures.

The text editor approach is generally more flexible, and instead of a simple collection of strings, uses a collection (or tree) of structures that hold metadata about the section (type, formatting, whatever).

The best approach depends on your needs:

- Are sections nestable?
- Will this be rendered?
- If so, do section "types" need specific rendering?
- *Are* there section "types", or are they all the same?
- Will the text in question be edited before, during, or after sectioning?
- Etc.